# How to modify existing function to cache variables from a previous call and pass it into another function call within?

Tags: python, function, design-patterns

I am currently working on a simulation code in python.

I have the following function:

```
def next(last_call=False):
  # do some stuff (not included in this skeleton code)
  if last_call:
    terminate_sim()
  else:
    state = function_that_returns_state()
```

This `next` and `function_that_returns_state` function was previously called `n+1` and `n` times a day, respectively, where `n` is typically between 20-40.

We need to add a new feature in the code, where now `next` and `function_that_returns_state` needs to be called `n + 2` and `n+1` times a day, respectively, but the last time `function_that_returns_state` needs to be called, `function_that_returns_state` needs to return 2 additional variables and those 2 variables will then be used on the last call to `next`, where `last_call` is set to `True`, and those 2 variables need to be passed into `terminate_sim`.

Currently, before the additional of the new call, we have something like below:

```
def function_that_returns_state()
  # do a lot of computations
  # compute var1, var2, state

  return state
```

For the additional call, we need to return `var1, var2`. So one way to do this is just to change the return signature of `function_that_returns_state` to

```
  return state, var1, var2
```

and call it like

```
state, var1, var2 = function_that_returns_state()
```

But the problem with this design is the `var1, var2` is only used 1 out of `n+1` times, so I'm not sure if this design is great. Is there another approach to this issue?

The second problem is the new feature we're adding requires the call to `terminate_sim` to be bifurcated as when the new feature is enabled requires `var1, var2` to be passed into `terminate_sim`. So it looks something like below

```
def next(last_call=False):
  # do some stuff (not included in this skeleton code)
  if last_call:
    if enable_new_feature:
      terminate_sim(we need to pass in var1, var2 here from the previous call to next)
    else:
      terminate_sim()
  else:
    state, var1, var2 = function_that_returns_state()
```

What are the ways in which we can cache `var1, var2` from the previous call so that it can be passed into the current call? One thing I can think of is to define attributes for `next`, e.g.,

```
def next(last_call=False):
  # do some stuff (not included in this skeleton code)
  if last_call:
    if enable_new_feature
      terminate_sim(run_next.var1, run_next.var2)
    else:
      terminate_sim()
  else:
    state, run_next.var1, run_next.var2 = function_that_returns_state()
```

Are there other ways to accomplish this?